# GRAND Stack queries always returns NULL

Tags: javascript, neo4j, graphql, apollo

I am trying to setup a GRAND STACK project with a remote neo4j database, the following is the code for the very basic connection:

```
const { Neo4jGraphQL } = require("@neo4j/graphql");
const neo4j = require("neo4j-driver");
const { ApolloServer } = require("apollo-server");

const typeDefs = `
    type Feature {
        id: Int
        name: String @cypher(statement: "MATCH (n:feature) RETURN n LIMIT 25")
    }

    type Symptom {
        id: Int
        name: String @cypher(statement: "MATCH (n:symptom) RETURN n LIMIT 25")
    }
    type Query {
        features: [Feature],
        symptoms: [Symptom]
    }
`;

const driver = neo4j.driver(
    "bolt://serverip:7687",
    neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "hello-hello-hello")
);

const neoSchema = new Neo4jGraphQL({ typeDefs, driver });

// const resolvers = {
//   Query: {
//     feature: () => feature,
//   },
// };

const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema: neoSchema.schema,
    context: ({ req }) => ({ req }),
    // resolvers
});

server.listen(4000).then(() => console.log("Online"));
```

And I'm making the following query:

```
query Query {
  symptoms {
    name
  }
}
```

The query always returns null. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j GraphQL autogenerates the queries and mutations for you. In your `typeDefs` remove the manual queries:

```
type Query {
    features: [Feature]
    symptoms: [Symptom]
}
```